# Linker fails to link inline functions defined in header, switching functions to static works

Tags: c, linker, build-error

I have two files, main.c and lib.h with the following contents. note i'm programming this in a freestanding environment.

```c
//main.c

#include <lib.h>

int main(void)
{
  char* t = "str";

  if(strisalnum(t)) printf("alnum\n");
  if(strisdec(t)) printf("dec\n");
  if(strishex(t)) printf("hex\n");
  if(strisalpha(t)) printf("isalpha\n");
  if(strisupper(t)) printf("strisupper\n");
  if(strislower(t)) printf("strislower\n");

  if(strisself("hello", "hEllo")) printf("strisself\n");
}
```

```c
//lib.h
// code...
inline bool inrange(intn cmp, intn lower, intn higher)  { return cmp >= lower && cmp <= higher; }

inline bool isalnum(char cmp)           { return inrange(cmp, 0x30, 0x39) || inrange(cmp, 0x41, 0x5A) || inrange(cmp, 0x61, 0x7A); }
inline bool isdec(char cmp)             { return inrange(cmp, 0x30, 0x39); }
inline bool ishex(char cmp)             { return inrange(cmp, 0x30, 0x39) || inrange(cmp, 0x3a, 0x36) || inrange(cmp, 0x61, 0x66); }
inline bool isalpha(char cmp)           { return inrange(cmp, 0x41, 0x5A) || inrange(cmp, 0x61, 0x7A); }
inline bool isupper(char cmp)           { return inrange(cmp, 0x41, 0x5A); }
inline bool islower(char cmp)           { return inrange(cmp, 0x61, 0x7A); }
inline bool isself(char in, char cmp)   { return cmp == in || isalpha(in) && isalpha(cmp) && ((cmp - 0x20 == in) || (cmp + 0x20 == in)); }
inline char toupper(char in)            { return islower(in) ? in + 20 : in; }
inline char tolower(char in)            { return isupper(in) ? in - 20 : in; }

inline bool  strisalnum(char* cmp)          { for(int i = 0; cmp[i]; i++) if(!isalnum(cmp[i]))  return false; return true; }     
inline bool  strisdec(char* cmp)            { for(int i = 0; cmp[i]; i++) if(!isdec(cmp[i]))    return false; return true; } 
inline bool  strishex(char* cmp)            { for(int i = 0; cmp[i]; i++) if(!ishex(cmp[i]))    return false; return true; } 
inline bool  strisalpha(char* cmp)          { for(int i = 0; cmp[i]; i++) if(!isalpha(cmp[i]))  return false; return true; } 
inline bool  strisupper(char* cmp)          { for(int i = 0; cmp[i]; i++) if(!isupper(cmp[i]))  return false; return true; } 
inline bool  strislower(char* cmp)          { for(int i = 0; cmp[i]; i++) if(!islower(cmp[i]))  return false; return true; } 
inline bool  strisself(char* in, char* cmp) { for(int i = 0; in[i] || cmp[i]; i++) if(!isself(in[i], cmp[i])) return false; return true; }  
inline char* strtoupper(char* in)           { for(int i = 0; in[i]; i++) toupper(in[i]);        return in; }
inline char* strtolower(char* in)           { for(int i = 0; in[i]; i++) tolower(in[i]);        return in; }
```

however when I compile and link this, I get:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccygL7SU.ltrans0.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x418b): undefined reference to `strisalnum'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccygL7SU.ltrans0.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x41e9): undefined reference to `strisself'
```

removing these functions from main, marking them as static, or replacing them with a version that just returns true fixes this error. I am wondering what about these two functions causes this error?

EDIT: linking part of makefile

```
CFLAGS_BOOT := -ffreestanding -flto -fno-stack-protector -fshort-wchar -mno-red-zone -I src -I ../common -Ofast -D QEMUBUILD=1  -mno-ms-bitfields
LFLAGS_BOOT := -nostdlib -flto -Wl,-dll -shared -Wl,--subsystem,10 -e efi_main -Ofast 
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc $(LFLAGS_BOOT) -o $(TEMPDIR)/BOOTX64.EFI $(BOOT_OBJ_FILES) $(COM_OBJ_FILES)
```

Comment: Did you not get errors for passing char * when char is expected?

Comment: @stark no, where would i get that error?

Comment: Perhaps, this kind of problem : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inline-function-in-c/

Comment: @Stef1611 you are right, I completely forgot you need to mark inline functions as static when putting them in a header.

Comment: "you need to mark inline functions as static when putting them in a header" - this is wrong, marking inline functions as `static` prevents linker from combining duplicate definitions in multiple `.o` files if inlining fails.